# Consolidate each row of dataframe returning a dataframe into ouput dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am looking for help in a scenario where I have a scala dataframe PARENT. I  need to

- loop through each record in PARENT dataframe
- Query the records from a database based on a filter using ID value of
  parent (the output of this step is dataframe)
- append few attributes from parent to queried dataframe

  Ex:

  ```
       ParentDF  
       id       parentname 
       1        X
       2        Y

       Queried Dataframe for id 1

       id queryid  name
       1  23       lobo
       1  45       sobo
       1  56       aobo


       Queried Dataframe for id 2

       id queryid  name
       2  53       lama
       2  67       dama
       2  56       pama
  ```

```
Final output required :
        id  parentname  queryid   name
        1   X           23       lobo
        1   X           45       sobo
        1   X           56       aobo
        2   Y           53       lama
        2   Y           67       dama
        2   Y           56       pama
```

Update1:

I tried using foreachpartition and use foreach internally to loop through each record and got below error.

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame. An implicit Encoder[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] is needed to store org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
             falttenedData.map(row=>{


I need to do this with scalability plz. Any help is really appreciated.
```

Comment: have you ever tried using the 
import spark.implicits._ ?

Comment: I think you should try using [`mapPartitions()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#mapPartitions[U](func:Iterator[T]=%3EIterator[U])(implicitevidence$7:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) not `foreachPartition`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pretty straightforward, you just need to `join` your parentDF and your other one.

```
parentDF.join(
    otherDF,
    Seq("id"),
    "left"
)
```

As you're caring about scalability, In case your "otherDF" is quite small (it has less than 10K rows for example with 2-3 cols), you should consider using [broadcast](https://medium.com/yipitdata-engineering/how-to-use-broadcasting-for-more-efficient-joins-in-spark-2d53a336b02b) join : `parentDF.join(broadcast(otherDF), Seq("id"), "left)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.join` method on a dataframe for this one.

Some example code would be something like this:

```
val df = Seq((1, "X"), (2, "Y")).toDF("id", "parentname")
df.show
+---+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
| id|parentname|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+---+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|  1|         X|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|  2|         Y|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+---+----------+

val df2 = Seq((1, 23, "lobo"), (1, 45, "sobo"), (1, 56, "aobo"), (2, 53, "lama"), (2, 67, "dama"), (2, 56, "pama")).toDF("id", "queryid",  "name")
df2.show
+---+-------+----+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
| id|queryid|name|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+---+-------+----+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|  1|     23|lobo|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|  1|     45|sobo|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|  1|     56|aobo|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|  2|     53|lama|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|  2|     67|dama|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|  2|     56|pama|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+---+-------+----+

val output=df.join(df2, Seq("id"))
output.show
+---+----------+-------+----+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
| id|parentname|queryid|name|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+---+----------+-------+----+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  1|         X|     23|lobo|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  1|         X|     45|sobo|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  1|         X|     56|aobo|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  2|         Y|     53|lama|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  2|         Y|     67|dama|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|  2|         Y|     56|pama|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+---+----------+-------+----+
```

Hope this helps! :)